# Does dynamic type choice break strict aliasing in C?

Tags: c, strict-aliasing

Let's say that I have some code that looks like this:

```
void foo(void* obj, int type)
{
    TypeA* a = (TypeA*)obj;
    TypeB* b = (TypeB*)obj;
    TypeC* c = (TypeC*)obj;

    if( type == 1 ) {
        // code that uses "a"
    }
    else if( type == 2 ) {
        // code that uses "b"
    }
    else if( type == 3 ) {
        // code that uses "c"
    }
}
```

I'm curious to know whether or not this function breaks strict aliasing a
priori, or if the validity of the function depends on how it's actually used.
A certain part of me wants to hope that things will work out fine if I only
ever used the function as `foo(&objectOfTypeA, 1)`, `foo(&objectOfTypeB, 2)`,
or `foo(&objectOfTypeC, 3)`. Yet I've only know about aliasing errors for a
few days, and so I worry that the function `foo()` is broken right from the
start simply because it casts the incoming void* to various different types to
begin with.

Comment: Unless your Types have the same alignment requirements as obj argument, your approach is broken.

Comment: @this: Incorrect.  Conversions from `void *` are always permissible, see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

This does not break strict aliasing, because you only access `*obj` through the correct type.  Casting `obj` does not result in access to `*obj`.

### The strict aliasing rule

Strict aliasing only applies to accessing an object, not to pointer manipulations.
You can manipulate the pointer all you want.

From n1570 §6.5 ¶7

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of the following types...

Since you're not accessing `*obj` but just `obj`, the strict aliasing rule is not violated.

### Conversions

The second question here is whether the conversions are permissible.  The answer is yes, because you can convert a `void *` to any other object pointer type.  The `void` type is special, it is the only type with this property.

```
int *i;
void *ptr = &i;
float *f = ptr; // Permissible
```

The standard is silent on what the value of `f` is.  In other words, while the conversion is permissible, there is nothing useful you can do with `f`.  You can't even convert it back to `void *`.

This is explained in n1570 §6.3.2.3 ¶1:

> A pointer to `void` may be converted to or from a pointer to any object type.  A pointer to any object type may be converted to a pointer to `void` and back again, the result shall compare equal to the original pointer.

So, to repeat, the conversion is *always permissible* but not useful in any way.

Comment: It is undefined behavior if obj has different alignment requirements than one the TypeX types when assigning pointer ( first three lines )

Comment: Oh, very interesting. So it's UB if the alignments are mismatched, even if the pointers are never used? Nothing more than the cast already breaks it?

Comment: I don't see how the alignment requirements of `obj` matter, either for `obj` itself or what `obj` points to. Any pointer type regardless of the alignment requirements of the type pointed to can be converted to `void *` and then converted back to that original pointer type. Which is exactly what happens here. As for the alignment requirements of `obj` itself, there's no requirement its initializer have the same alignment.

Comment: @this: Incorrect.  n1570 section 6.3.2.3 paragraph 1: "A pointer to `void` may be converted to or from a pointer to any object type."  It is not undefined behavior.

Comment: @DietrichEpp 6.3.2.3 para 7: *A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the
resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is
undefined.* Also read this: https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/EXP36-C.+Do+not+cast+pointers+into+more+strictly+aligned+pointer+types

Comment: @this: That's not applicable.  `obj` has type `void *`, and is therefore not "a pointer to an object type".

Comment: @DietrichEpp No obj is contained in void*, but has whatever type it was declared with. The intermediate pointer is void*, but that doesn't matter. What matters is the original type and casted type( which is later used ). If they are not compatible you break strict aliasing. If they don't have the same alignment requirements you get potentially undefined b.

Comment: @this: That is irrelevant.  `obj` is a pointer to `void`.  It is the **result** of a conversion from another pointer type, but it is still itself a pointer to `void`.  So conversions to pointers to all other object pointer types are valid.  You're not reading the text strictly enough.

Comment: "...there is nothing useful you can do with f. You can't even convert it back to void *". I think you CAN convert it back to `void *` and even going back to `int *`. The result is not guaranteed to be the same as `i`, of course.